# Add status image next to a form field

Tags: html

**I am trying to put a status image (showing a tick if email is correct or cross if not) next to the email field in my form.** 
The problem is my registration form is using the table method , so the image is not showing next to the field but below it. Can anyone help me out here?

This is what I tried to do but still not work the way I want it to.

```
<table width="500" border="0">
<tr><td width="210" height="45">Email:</td><td>
<input type="text" size="40" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" onkeyup="checkEmail(this.value);" onblur="checkEmail(this.value);" maxlength="60" />
**<img id="status" src="images/bad.png" style="margin-left:5px; vertical-align:middle;" alt="Status" /></td></tr>**
</table>
```

Comment: It is because the `<td>` has not enough space to fit in both text field and the image.

Comment: Do you know how I could solve this issue?

Comment: either add more width to the `<table>` or the 2nd `<td>`

Comment: Either increase the table width, or decrease the Email label cell width. Or, don't use tables for layout!

Comment: Ok I will try this, thanks. I will see if this works first

Comment: Create a label after your email field and append the image to that label using $("#statuslabel).html('<img src="images/bad.png" ~');, you can also use .after instead of .html

Comment: Hey thanks a lot guys, It worked. I just increased the table width to 600, and is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `<td>` has not enough space to fit in both text field and the image.

either add more width to the `<table>` or the 2nd `<td>` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is of a check mark and an x, just use the unicode equivalents:

- `&#10004;` = ✔
- `&#10008;` = ✘

And simply get rid of the image altogether.

Answer (score 1):

All it needs right now is space to fit in.

```
<table width="650px" border="0">
<tr><td width="210px" height="45">Email:</td><td>
<input type="text" size="40" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" onkeyup="checkEmail(this.value);" onblur="checkEmail(this.value);" maxlength="60" />
**<img id="status" src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="125px" height="50px" style="margin-left:5px; vertical-align:middle;" alt="Status" /></td></tr>**
</table>
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S52nF/), what changed is the size of the table containing the column. You may either reduce the input width or let it more space by increasing the table width.